# Trying to call a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code all I need to do is call a function which will write the contents to a dynamic div

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function getComments(id)
{
  alert(id);
}
var resultSet="";
function CreateDiv()
{

resultSet+="<br/><div id='"+rows.data[i].id+"'></div><script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> getComments("+rows.data[i].id+"); <\/script>";
}
window.onload=CreateDiv;
</script>
```

The function getComments is not being called at all

What's that I am missing here

Comment: Where is `getComments` supposed to be called?? It is not.

Comment: the above code block is written inside <body> tag, so as soon as the body loads the getComments should have been called, but its not getting called at all

Comment: lots of variables in the create div dont make sense

Comment: I format the JavaScript code. It now becomes obvious why the `getComments` function is not called. Hint: check the quotes.

Comment: I can NOT see the function being called. Please specify where. The fn name is only passed inside a string, which is assigned to a variable, which is used nowhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing the `createDiv` function with this:

```
function CreateDiv(){
    resultSet += "<br/><div id='"+rows.data[i].id+"'></div>" + getComments(rows.data[i].id);
}
```

It should work flawlessly.

Comment: Did this actually work, @Sandhurst? I thought you would still have the issues with undefined variables that T.J. points out in his answer.

Comment: I fail to see why someone downvoted the only straight and acceptable answer.

Comment: You'll end up with the string "undefined" appearing in the `resultSet` string (since `getComments` doesn't return a value, so the result of the call to it is `undefined`). Better to just call it separately from appending to the string, if that's really the behavior the OP wants (and I assume it is, as this is the accepted answer).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sure, but I'm assuming that the author was trying to write a function that returns a string from `getComments`. And also, `var resultSet = "";` initiates the variable.

Comment: Fair enough (on the assumption). (I didn't say `resultSet` wasn't initialized; at least, not since an hour ago when Felix pointed out the line I missed.) BTW, I don't understand the downvote either, it seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems there.

1. You're referencing `rows` without defining it anywhere, which will cause an exception.
2. Assuming you define `rows` somewhere you haven't shown, the code's just creating a string containing a `script` tag and putting that string in `resultSet`. To cause the code inside the script tag to run, you'd have to assign `resultSet` to `innerHTML` on some element.
3. There's an extra `)` in your call to `getComments` within the generated script.

Separately: Your `id` values would appear to be numbers (this is based on your passing them into `getComments` with no quotes around them). Note that using `id` values starting with a digit is allowed in HTML5, but not in earlier versions of HTML and not in CSS, so it's probably best avoided.

There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're actually trying to do, you may consider a separate question outlining the goal, how you've approached it so far, and asking for alternatives.

Comment: `resultSet` is defined: `var resultSet="";` (above `CreateDiv`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you **break the code down into steps** while you debug it. Specifically where you populate resultSet. Break it down at each plus sign. Then you can step through it and see how it is being populated.

```
resultSet+="<br/><div id='";
resultSet+=rows.data[i].id;
```

and so on.

Secondly, have a look in View Source to see what this looks like on the page when you run it. Does the HTML look properly formed?

Also, I am questioning whether that final  `<\/script>` in resultSet is correct.

Comment: *"Also, I am questioning whether that final <\/script> in resultSet is correct"* It is, the resulting string will be "</script>" because escaping a slash in JavaScript just results in a slash. This is a common way of preventing the HTML parser from seeing "</script>" in the string and prematurely terminating the script block in which that string appears.